# AVPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem not working on iOS 4.3.3+

Tags: objective-c, ios, avplayer

I have an audio player that I'm building using AVPlayer.

Currently, I keep the `player` instance around and when I need to swap tracks (either from a manual selection or the track has reached the end) I create a new `AVPlayerItem` and I call `replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem` with the new item.

According to the docs, `replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem` is an asynchronous operation, so I also observe the *currentItem* key path of the player.  When that gets called, I tell my player to play.

Here is the relevant code:

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:CHStreamingAudioPlayer_PlayerItemStatusChangedContext];

if (!_player) {
    _player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem]; 
    [_player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"          options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:CHStreamingAudioPlayer_PlayerStatusChangedContext];
    [_player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem"     options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:CHStreamingAudioPlayer_PlayerCurrentItemChangedContext];
} else {
    [_player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
}
```

And here is the key value observation callback:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == CHStreamingAudioPlayer_PlayerCurrentItemChangedContext) {
        NSLog(@"Player's current item changed! Change dictionary: %@", change);
        if (_player.currentItem) {
            [self play]; //<---- doesn't get called
        }
    } else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

On iOS 4.3.3 (and iOS 5) my key observation method is called but `_player.currentItem` is always `nil`.  On 4.2.1 and 4.3.2 this property contains the actual value.  This method is never called again.  So in essence, replacing seems to always fail.

This seems like a bug, but perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Did the answer below by Dunja resolve your problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had this issue with iOS 5 (including 5.0.1). It used to work fine on iOS 4.x.

There are two ways to workaround this, release and recreate your `AVPlayer` with the desired `AVPlayerItem`s each time you need to swap tracks. Or, simply call `replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:` on the main thread.

I tried both options and they worked fine.

Credits to: [Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/561368)

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing similar problems. You probably got started from [AVPlayerDemoPlaybackViewController from Apple sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Listings/Classes_AVPlayerDemoPlaybackViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010101-Classes_AVPlayerDemoPlaybackViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_8) like me. Maybe the problem why `currentItem` is `nil` is because it's not loaded yet or ready for playback (my problem was I couldn't get the duration of the new `AVPlayerItem`).

You could try starting the playback when observed status of the `currentItem` is `ReadyToPlay`.

```
AVPlayerStatus status = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] integerValue];
    switch (status) {
        case AVPlayerStatusUnknown: {
            NSLog(@"PLAYER StatusUnknown");
        }
            break;
        case AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay: {
            NSLog(@"PLAYER ReadyToPlay");
            [self play];
        }
            break;
        case AVPlayerStatusFailed: {
            AVPlayerItem *playerItem = (AVPlayerItem *)object;
            [self handleError: [playerItem.error localizedDescription]];
        }
            break;
    }
```

I don't know if this will wok for you, I didn't try this on lower or higher than 4.3.4 iPad, so I guess I'll run into complications soon.