# Adjust Quality while streaming video with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, video-streaming, avplayer

How can I able to set low or high quality video withstreaming video with AVPlayer?

My code is as follow:

```
self.videoPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:videoUrl];

    videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.videoPlayerItem];
    videoPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    videoPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer layer];
    [videoPlayerLayer setPlayer:videoPlayer];
    [videoPlayerLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
```

**Thanks for your time**

Comment: I guess this is only one possible solution to switch URLs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790126/avplayer-switching-stream-quality-while-playing

Comment: @Injectios, I don't have separate URL for low quality
I have just one URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can lower the video quality/bitrate by setting `AVPlayerItem`'s [preferredPeakBitRate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1388541-preferredpeakbitrate).

Re-set it to zero to get the usual "highest quality/bitrate supported by your connection" behaviour.

N.B. A bitrate less than or equal to `preferredPeakBitRate` must be available for this to work, e.g. in an HLS stream.

Comment: I tried to set it but no effected.

I tried with value 1, it is same as highest

Comment: are you able to explain me this?

 indicated bitrate is 2368563.665595
 observerd bitrate is 690212.603009
 preferred bitrate is 100000.000000

Comment: I don't think `preferredPeakBitRate` can conjure bitrates that aren't actually provided by the server. What bitrates are available in your stream?

Comment: Server bit rate is 20 Lacs.

Comment: The server doesn't offer any other bitrates?

Comment: no, I am uploading video with 20 lacs bitrate to server & get the same video from server by URL

Comment: So only 1 bitrate is available? Ps what are lacs?

Comment: 20 lacs means 20,00,000. 
yes, I am uploading video with 20,00,000 bitrate via ios devices & that will save to server. After that Server provides me a URL to playback it.

Comment: If you've only got one bitrate available then you have nothing to vary. Have you looked at HLS?

Comment: yes, but I am very confused with all configuration with HLS

Comment: can you let me know any feedback?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman, can you provide demo code like how to change quality with bitrate?

Comment: Just set the player item's `preferredPeakBitRate` - but I think you can only lower the rate using this method.

Comment: How can you confirm that this is actually working in code? I am definitely seeing the rendition switch to lower qualities (we have different renditions with burned in images indicating their quality), but I'm wondering how to confirm that the bitrate of the AVPlayer's currentItem is actually going up or down. It seems that the observedBitrate value of the accessLog event doesn't show any indication of this.